# Storing everything after a certain word in a line, in a list- Regex

Tags: python

So I have a line,

```
unicomp6.unicomp.net - - [01/Jul/1995:00:00:14 -0400] "GET /images/NASA-logosmall.gif HTTP/1.0" 200 786
```

And I want to store everything after HTTP/1.0" (so those two numbers) into list, how would I do this using regex? I have read the docs on them but they confuse me a bit.

Comment: What about just getting "the last two whitespace-delimited strings"? Do you want them as `int`'s?

Comment: If you're just doing this to learn about regex, then it's fine to prefer an answer that uses regex. But be aware that code using built-in `str` methods can often be _significantly_ faster than regex-based solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [regex101](https://regex101.com/), to construct regular expressions which suit your need.

For your particular example, the following RE would work:

```
HTTP\/1.0.(.*$)
```

Explanation:

Capture in group everthing after `HTTP 1.0"`

Gives output:

```
` 200 786`
```

Answer (score 2):

```
import re
text = 'unicomp6.unicomp.net - - [01/Jul/1995:00:00:14 -0400] "GET /images/NASA-logosmall.gif HTTP/1.0" 200 786'
regex = r'HTTP/1.0".*$'
match = re.search(regex, text)
list_with_numbers = match.groups()[0].split()
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need regex for this, you can use built-in `str` methods. Eg,

```
s = 'unicomp6.unicomp.net - - [01/Jul/1995:00:00:14 -0400] "GET /images/NASA-logosmall.gif HTTP/1.0" 200 786'
data = s.partition('HTTP/1.0" ')
nums = data[2].split()
print(nums)
```

**output**

```
['200', '786']
```

You could also use `.split()` instead of `.partition()`, but I think `.partition()` is more natural here. Note that the numbers stored in `nums` are strings, so you'll need to add a conversion step if you need to do arithmetic with them.

Here's an example using `.split()` instead of `.partition()` that converts the number strings to integers.

```
data = s.split('HTTP/1.0"')
nums = [int(u) for u in data[1].split()]
print(nums)
```

**output**

```
[200, 786]
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have to use a regular expression? If not, you could do this:

```
>>> lines = ['unicomp6.unicomp.net - - [01/Jul/1995:00:00:14 -0400] "GET /images/NASA-logosmall.gif HTTP/1.0" 200 786']
>>> 
>>> numbers = [line.split()[-2:] for line in lines]
>>> numbers
[['200', '786']]
>>>
```

This assumes that "the last two whitespace-delimited strings" is equivalent to what you want.

Comment: It's not clear from the OP that there will always be exactly 2 items after `HTTP/1.0"`; hopefully, Nick will clarify that for us. OTOH, IMO it's nice to keep things flexible rather than doing code that will only handle 2 items. Also, it's seems a little wasteful to make `.split()` carve up the input on every whitespace when we don't need those earlier substrings.